# Square Integration in iOS

Tags: ios, api, sdk, square

I am trying to find out some technical doc,blog or sample code, which can help me to integrate Squareup API into iOS.
I have googled it already, which didn't helped me much.
I have the android github code for reference.

I have also found the feasibility of squareup in iOS, as you can check this app:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drchrono-emr/id363897223?mt=8

This app has used the squareup, that means, it is available to integrate in iOS.

Looking forward  for the suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Just because they use Square in their app doesn't mean it is publicly available. They may have a partnership with Square for this.

Comment: yes you are right, but squareup has been integrated into several other apps also.

Comment: Perhaps you can try contacting the developers of these apps to see how they do it. My guess is they are in a private beta, or have a partnership with Square. There does not seem to be a publicly available sdk

Comment: right....thanks for suggestion coneybeare...appreciate the gesture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square does not offer an API. [[Source1]](https://help.squareup.com/customer/portal/articles/159619-can-i-process-payments-online-) [[Source2]](https://help.squareup.com/customer/portal/articles/357440-does-square-offer-an-api-)

Their [official Github account](https://github.com/square) does have a deprecated (as of April 2012) [android api](https://github.com/square/android-api) that will not work. I would advise looking elsewhere for in-app payment solutions.

Also keep in mind that in-app payments are a gray area in the iOS terms of service. If you are selling something in the app, it must be available for sale outside of the app as well. Selling items through the app only will have to use Apple's In-App Purchase framework so they get their 30% cut.

Comment: hi, i want to implement square payments in my application in android but after searching allot , i did not find any kind of sdk in android or how to use the API or any demo.

Comment: This answer is out of date (Square does have an API), and the paragraph regarding Apple's iOS terms of service is also outdated. You can indeed sell items within your app that don't use IAPs.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2014 it does look like they offer an API:

https://connect.squareup.com/

Comment: hi, i want to implement square payments in my application in android but after searching allot , i did not find any kind of sdk in android or how to use the API or any demo.